# Cost effective way to finish this shower?

Tags: shower, sliding-glass-door

I have an unfinished stand-up shower seen in the picture. I got estimates for frameless glass (a look that I like) and all of them were in excess of $3000. If I give up the idea of it looking super nice, but refuse to have a shower bar with a curtain, are there good economic options for finishing it off? Anything pre-fab that can be adjusted in the field?

Thanks!

[image: The base of the unfinished shower]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, not really (someone screwed the pooch with that mirror). TL;DR: it's curtains for you, or bust ($$$).

If I had to guess, **any type of custom shower door is going to cost $1~2k *installed*.** So, you should get some estimates and see where you're at. If they all want 2.5k for glazed doors, why not go all the way and get what you want? Perhaps one of them will do some sort of financing?

Take some really good measurements; you *might* be able to squeeze a complete door set behind that half wall, to make this a feasible DiY project (but that will probably lead to a mold problem).

ATM, my town is in "construction season" (summer); **wait for winter** to come around and everyone's prices should drop. Use a curtain in the meantime, or at least until you can secure a reasonable bid.

---

As I understand it, **cutting tempered glass is basically out of the question**. So this is either going to be full-on custom, or ad-hoc schlock. You've literally backed yourself into a corner here. (who put that mirror in?)

[DiY - cut tempered glass](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-cut-tempered-glass), "Step 2 - *Anneal the Glass*"

Good luck with that!... I sincerely doubt you have a 6' oven.

---

**There are several different types of corner shower doors that come as kits.** Using 2 out of the three panels (and a small filler strip of 'C' channel if necessary) might do the trick, but you'd better measure *everything* extremely well...

Good luck in your search, these days "adjustable" means it can be ever so *slightly* out of plumb, and still hang frameless doors. To the best of my knowledge, **no one sells a glass door with actually 'adjustable' (non-glass) side panels** but someone might.

---

I have seen [**accordion style (folding) plastic (PVC) shower doors**](http://bathtubdo.com/pvc-folding-bathtub-door/); the hard part is going to be finding one that has a track that will fit your angled base, and then you would 'simply' cut it to size. Or just get a straight one and modify it.

Comment: Did I forget to mention that I hate working with glass, and the one time I helped a 'professional' install a frameless door it was a bitch and it still leaks... Doors of any kind are not DiY IMO, especially glass ones that need to be watertight.

Comment: I agree with @Mazura (+1) in that you could fairly easily buy a "corner shower door kit" at a big-box store and use just 2 panels, filling the short leg (with the interfering mirror wall) with a wall from pan to top of shower door. http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/85/85c978af-f7d4-4655-b8a2-ce4623068aab_400.jpg

Comment: In general it looks like the job was half conceived, the left side would need a custom pane (~150$) as it appears to be too wide of an area for a channel only, so it would be a mix of big box shower door kit and custom glass, or fully custom glass, in either case, a homeowner completing this job isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to determine what manufacturer and model the shower base is. You can then research that info, as most manufacturers offer enclosure kits for their products. Most stock enclosure kits run between $500 to $1500, depending on style and materials; acrylic vs tempered glass, for example.